# Links in dropdown menu aren't being followed

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

When user click on ABC, it should go to abc.php. But it wont. If I return true as follows in jquery code, it wont work the slide down when click on Sub. Please give me a solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $js(document).ready(function() {

        //Class 'contentContainer' refers to 'li' that has child with it.
        //By default the child ul of 'contentContainer' will be set to 'display:none'
        $js("#treeMenu li").toggle(

            function() { // START FIRST CLICK FUNCTION
                $js(this).children('ul').slideDown()
                if ($js(this).hasClass('contentContainer')) {
                    $js(this).removeClass('contentContainer').addClass('contentViewing');
                }

            }, // END FIRST CLICK FUNCTION

            function() { // START SECOND CLICK FUNCTION
                $js(this).children('ul').slideUp()

                if ($js(this).hasClass('contentViewing')) {
                    $js(this).removeClass('contentViewing').addClass('contentContainer');
                }

            } // END SECOND CLICK FUNCTIOn
            //return true; If used this, slide down is not working
        ); // END TOGGLE FUNCTION
    }); // END DOCUMENT READY
</script>
```

html as follows

```
<div id="left_menu">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;margin-bottom: 0px;color: #000000">Our Ministry</h2>
    <ul id="treeMenu">
        <li><a href="abc.php">ABC</a></li>
        <li><a href="def.php">DEF</a></li>
        <li><a href="ghi.php">GHI</a></li>
        <li class="contentContainer"><a href="#">Sub</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="jkl.php">JKL</a></li>
                <li><a href="mno.php">MNO</a></li>
                <li><a href="pqr.php">PQR</a></li>
                <li><a href="stu.php">STU</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What version jQuery are you using? `.toggle` changed somewhere along the line.

Comment: Off topic: The `href` attribute must not be empty. Use `#` or `javascript:void(0)`.

Comment: Are you sure that you have this alias `$js` for jQuery?... Besides I don't know why this wouldn't work.

Comment: have the alias $js for jquery also.

Comment: Using the # is also wont work.

Comment: Do you want to slide-up/slide-down the sub-nav(if li has sub-nav) ?

Comment: In the above codes no problem with menu. It works fine. The problem is that not go to the href atribute page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can simplify like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8s923/3

```
<li class="parent contentContainer"><a href="#">Sub</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#treeMenu li.parent > a").click(function (e) { // START FIRST CLICK FUNCTION
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('contentContainer contentViewing')
            .children('ul').slideToggle();
    }); // END TOGGLE FUNCTION
}); // END DOCUMENT READY
```

The solution is to only apply `preventDefault` to the specific anchors that operate the dropdown menu by giving them a class that isn't toggled.

Don't forget to reapply your alias.

Comment: when I click JKL, slide is going to up only.